# systemd service not works in docker

Tags: docker, service, systemd, ubuntu-20.04, systemctl

my environment is under docker image(ubuntu 20.04), and **i want to use systemd to start my service after every time i start mydocker**, i have my own .service file here:

/etc/systemd/system/my.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=my test
Documentation=man:test auto(8) man:test_config(5)

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/test.sh
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/root/test.sh have been chmod 777:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello~"  > /usr/local/test.log
exit 0
```

and I did follows operation:

```
systemctl enable my.service
docker stop mydocker
docker start mydocker
docker exec -it mydocker bash
```

but after I start mydocker, I didn't see /root/test.sh executed, and i check service status like this:

```
my.service - my test auto
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my.service, enabled)
    Active: inactive (dead)
```

manually trigger service is okay:

```
root@:/# systemctl start my.service
root@:/# cat /usr/local/test.log 
hello~
```

did I omit something? or systemd could not work well in docker?

thanks.

Comment: Systemd doesn't work well in Docker.  I'd set your image to have `CMD /root/test.sh` to run the script as the main container process, and avoid systemd entirely here.

Comment: See [this post](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/is-there-any-concrete-and-acceptable-solution-for-running-systemd-inside-the-doc)  as well

Comment: i saw this might reasonable @DiogoSimões
 `docker run -it --rm \
  -e container=docker \
  --tmpfs /run \
  --tmpfs /tmp \
  -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
  --cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
  centos /sbin/init`
but i use ubuntu no /sbin/init found, seems docker aiming as micro server which apply systemd function as dockerfile CMD and docker running commands...

Answer (score 1):

#### suggestion #1

Docker images are expected to run an initial command/program specified in the docker image generation `dockerfile` properties:

> ENTRYPOINT

> CMD

See here: https://blog.knoldus.com/a-look-at-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-dockerfile/

#### suggestion #2

In your `/etc/systemd/system/my.service:` `[unit]` section add `Requires=Network.target` and `After=Network.target`:

Like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=my test
Documentation=man:test auto(8) man:test_config(5)
Requires=Network.target
After=Network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/test.sh
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### suggestion #3

Do not use systemd services in docker image.

Use `crontab` job at boot time.

https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/run-jobs-or-scripts-using-crontab-on-boot/

##### crontab job

```
@boot /root/test.sh
```

Comment: systemd does not work with docker, i tried it on vm or physical or virtual machine and it will work, but in docker it always fail. anyway, some replacement i will take, thanks.

Comment: systemd does actually work with docker for a user with correct capabilities included in `docker run` command options. But this is a security risk. Allowing docker user access to host systemd as well.